# Как сделать несколько серверов на Flask на порте 80 для разных доменов?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, flask, веб-сервер

Как сделать несколько серверов на Flask на порте 80 для разных доменов?
P.S.: У меня сервер на Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score -3):

Для запуска нескольких серверов Flask на порте 80 для разных доменов вам понадобится использовать несколько экземпляров приложения Flask и настроить проксирование запросов на соответствующие серверы. Вот основные шаги:

1. Установите необходимые пакеты Flask:

```
$ pip install flask
```

2. Создайте несколько файлов `app.py` для каждого сервера Flask. Каждый файл должен содержать отдельную конфигурацию для своего домена.

Например, создайте файлы `app1.py` и `app2.py` с следующим содержимым:

```py
# app1.py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'This is server 1'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

```py
# app2.py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'This is server 2'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

3. Настройте веб-сервер (например, Nginx или Apache) для проксирования запросов на соответствующие серверы Flask. Это можно сделать с помощью настройки виртуальных хостов.

Например, для Nginx создайте два конфигурационных файла `server1.conf` и `server2.conf` в директории `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`:

```
# server1.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain1.com;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;  # Проксируйте запросы на порт, на котором запущен первый сервер Flask
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

```
# server2.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain2.com;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5001;  # Проксируйте запросы на порт, на котором запущен второй сервер Flask
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

4. Перезапустите веб-сервер, чтобы применить изменения в конфигурации.

Теперь сервер Flask для `domain1.com` будет доступен по адресу `http://domain1.com`, а сервер Flask для `domain2.com` - по адресу `http://domain2.com`. Используйте соответствующие домены при настройке DNS-записей.

Comment: chatgpt? ой-ой...

Comment: "Каждый файл [app.py] должен содержать отдельную конфигурацию для своего домена." - а где?